# Trying to fade in images loaded from URL asynchronously in XCode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to load images from a URL and then assign them as background images for different UIButtons. I need to do this when a view appears.

My problem is that when I try to make the images fade in when they are loaded, the animation does not start until all of the images have loaded. I think this is because the animation code is read but that before it has time to be executed, the program starts loading a new image.

How can I make images fade in one after the other?

The following code is used to get the image (calling downloadImageByPrice atURL) and then does the animation.

```
-(void) obtainImage:(int)i atURL:(NSString *)URLString{

    UIImage *image = [self downloadImageByPrice:i atURL:URLString];

    // Make images fade in when they have been found
    [[_buttonArray objectAtIndex:i] setAlpha:0.0];

    [[_buttonArray objectAtIndex:i] setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeIn" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];

    [[_buttonArray objectAtIndex:i] setAlpha:1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

This method is used to load all the images one after the other. I want my loop to wait until each image has appeared before starting to load the next one.

```
-(void) loadAllImagesAtURL:(NSString *)URLString{
    for(int i =0; i<[_buttonArray count];i++){
        [self obtainImage:i atURL:URLString];
    }    
}
```

I have tried using selectors, or the completion^ method with no luck, but my understanding of those concepts is still pretty low.

Thank you

Comment: You should probably look into NSThread or NSOperation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out:

***ViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *buttonArray;
-(void) loadAllImagesAtURL:(NSString *)URLString;
- (UIImage *)downloadImageAtURL:(NSString *)urlString;
@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize buttonArray = _buttonArray;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setButtonArray:[NSMutableArray array]];
    int margin = 20;
    int buffer = 8;
    int width  = 100;
    int height = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1) {
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setAlpha:0.0];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(margin + ((width + buffer) * i), margin, width, height)];
        [btn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[self buttonArray] addObject:btn];
        [[self view] addSubview:btn];
    }
    [self loadAllImagesAtURL:@"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"];
}
-(void) loadAllImagesAtURL:(NSString *)URLString {
    static int i = -1;
    i = i + 1;
    if (i < [[self buttonArray] count]) {
        UIImage *image = [self downloadImageAtURL:URLString];
        // Make images fade in when they have been found
        [[_buttonArray objectAtIndex:i] setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                         animations:^{
                             [[_buttonArray objectAtIndex:i] setAlpha:1.0];
                         } 
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                             [self loadAllImagesAtURL:URLString];
                         }
         ];
    }
}
- (UIImage *)downloadImageAtURL:(NSString *)urlString {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    return image;
}
@end
```

For me, this creates 4 buttons (that are initially invisible) that fade in when the image is downloaded. Is this what you want?

Comment: That might be what I want! But do the images appear all at once, or do they fade in one after the other?

Comment: 1. They fade in one at a time. 2. If you tried the code, you would know that answer. :-)

Comment: And it worked! Thank you so much, excellent precise answer, you have no idea how long I worked on this!